# How to send text/html email in java?

Tags: java, html, sendmail

I set my Content to "text/html" but for some reason I'm getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.mail.MessagingException: IOException while sending message;
  nested exception is:
    java.io.IOException: "text/html" DataContentHandler requires String object, was given object of type class javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:1245)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:254)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
    at EmailSender.sendEmail(TestSendEmails.java:124)
    at EmailSender.sendEmail(TestSendEmails.java:130)
    at Main.main(Main.java:8)
```

Here is my code:

```
Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("work@gmail.com"));
message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(s.getEmailTo().replace(";", ",")));
message.setSubject(s.getEmailSubject());
message.setText(s.getEmailBody());
message.setContent(message, "text/html");
Transport.send(message);
```

Please let me know what should be changed in my code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `message.setContent("your body here", "text/html")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntax error here

```
 message.setContent(message, "text/html");// here you are passing object of type class javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage
```

correct is

```
message.setContent("your body here", "text/html")
```

Comment: Thanks! This works fine. I have one more question for you if you can help. How I can update my database table after I sent my email? I want to update my Sent On field in database with time/date when email has been sent. I do not know where I should implement that code inside of mine. Thanks in advance.

Comment: after `transport.close()` or `Transport.send(message)`  statement you suppose to write your `jdbc` code to update `column` in db.

Comment: Thank you. I was implementing my code at the wrong place.